# Keep logo centered in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a navbar menu for my website, but I am stacked. The concept is to have the logo in the middle of the navbar and the three menu options from left and the other three menu from right.

```
<header id="top-header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <ul class="menu" id="nav-menu">
         <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">MENU 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">MENU 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">MENU 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">MENU 6</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I tried to add a width to `<li>` with percentage like this which worked for the menu titles:

```
#top-header ul > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
    position: relative;
}
```

However, my problem now is the image with the logo. It doesn't stay on the center of the screen. The image is the whole navbar with the logo on the middle, so I was hoping to resize vertically the image when the browser change resolution.

```
#top-header .logo {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("img/menubar_logo.png");
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: It is a typo when I change the names of the classes when passing the code here. Thank you

Comment: Are `large-12` and `columns` your own classes, because they're not part of bootstrap. A bootstrap column would be `col-lg-12`.

Comment: There are from a wordpress template which use Twitter Bootstrap. They have the same CSS but with slightly different names.

Answer (score 0):

I would include the logo as the middle list element and turn it into a faux table. This will eliminate the need to define a width for the elements within.

http://jsfiddle.net/3pf4onbj/

**HTML**

```
<header id="top-header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <ul class="menu" id="nav-menu">
         <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">MENU 3</a></li>
         <li><div class="logo"></div></li>
         <li><a href="#">MENU 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">MENU 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">MENU 6</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  background:#ff0;
}
#top-header ul {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#top-header ul > li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
#top-header ul > li a {
  display:block;
  padding:3px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to check this answer. The structure of the menu is automatically created from the table. I can change the `divs` and the CSS, but the menu is too complicated to step inside.